# React - How to pass props via react-router v4 from one page to another?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, react-router-v4

I want to pass props not from parent to child but from one page to another using react router. I wasn't sure its even possible but found a few articles/posts here where it does seem possible. Based on what read my code should work, but it doesn't. Could anyone help?

**index.jsx:**

```
ReactDOM.render(<HashRouter><App /> </HashRouter>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

**App.jsx:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render (){
    return (
      <div>           
        <Switch history={browserHistory}>
          ...
          <Route exact path='/home/step1' component={Component1}/>
          <Route exact path='/home/step2' component={Component2}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
...
import { Switch, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
```

My 2 components

```
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      id: undefined
    }
    this.navigateToStep2=this.navigateToStep2.bind(this);
  }
  navigateToStep2(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    browserHistory.push({pathname: "/home/step2", state:{id: this.state.id}})
  }
}

import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
export default class Component2 extends React.Component {

render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello: {this.props.id}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I also tried is:

```
this.context.router.push({
  pathname: '/home/step2',
  state: {providerId: this.state.providerId}
})
```

This doesn't work as well but as I understand its because of router 4, I must use history browser now?

Comment: If you are not keen on using a store solution like Redux, you could use the `App` component to keep in its state the props you need for your routes and pass callback methods to both `Component1` and `Component2` to update such state.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if that is the best answer but I just found out how to do it:

Instead of pushing anything, I just put it insight my Link to the other page:

```
<Link to={{
     pathname: '/home/step2',
     state: { id: this.state.id }
     }}>GO
</Link>
```

then insight my other page, I can easy access it:

```
<h1>{this.props.location.state.id}</h1>
```

I still wonder why using browserHistory.push ... could make sense here, so if anyone know, it would be nice to know!

Answer (score 0):

1) But this line

`<Switch history={browserHistory}>`

are you sure about it? History should be provided to your router context provider (HashRouter in your case)

2) Then, this line

`browserHistory.push({pathname: "/home/step2", state:{id: this.state.id}})`

But surely you need to use `withRouter` hoc/decorator to access current history object, otherwise it cannot deal with the context where (I suppose) history state is kept. Or just use the `Link` component as mentioned in an answer above